# How to design this behaviour of changable contents

Tags: android

I am coming across a situation that I am not sure what the correct way to handle is.

I have the following layout

[image]

When this layout is used, the parent content will stay the same but the child content will change based on the buttons you click in the child content. So basically Child content will be become Child Content 2. Think of the child content as Linear layout that has bunch of texts and buttons.

My question what is the correct way to design this: 
I can think of 2 ways:
1- Activity where the child contents will be fragments
2- Activity where I dynamically load the different child content layouts
3- Activity where I create a layout xml for every parent+child laybout combination and then dynalically setContentView on the full layout
3- other ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4)Get a reference to the parent you want to insert it in, and dynamically add/remove views from it.

5)Put all the possible children in it in one layout and play with the visibility of the different children.

But realistically you're going to use 1 or 4.